# Do we use article with gerud in present simble with 'be'?

Tags: grammar, articles, gerunds, present-continuous, present-simple

I am wondering about the following pattern of sentence:

> The first and the main reason is ***the*** producing new goods for...

Do we need to put bold "the" to distinguish present continuous from present simple with gerund or that's obvious and we shouldn't use "the"?

Comment: That sentence does not look correct.  Did you find it somewhere, or did you write it?

Comment: I would either leave it out or change the sentence to '...the production of new goods...'.

Comment: I wrote this by my own

Comment: Even though, I want to know about pattern present simple + 'be' + gerund

Comment: *I wrote this **on my own*** or *I wrote this [**by**] **myself***, not ***...by my own***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we should use the article **the** because we are referring to a specific example of producing: the producing  ***of** new goods*.

Yes, the sentence could sound confusing if there is no article:

> The reason is producing new goods...

sounds like the present continuous.  But with the article you could not confuse it with the present continuous, and usually it is clear from context.    (The reason makes new goods?  That doesn't make sense.)

If you are referring to a general concept, you can either use **that** to clarify, like

> The reason is **that** producing goods is difficult

or sometimes it's just understood from context:

> My favorite thing is swimming

which clearly means "Swimming is my favorite thing to do", not "My favorite object performs the action of swimming right now."